# How do I stop images being distorted in Unity3d?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I am making an app in Unity but when I add graphics, they are distorted and out of proportion. I am able to use them, but they don't look good. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide us with a screen shot?

Comment: Not at the moment, I will when I can. It's basically just enlarged in one dimension (or compressed in the other, as far as I can tell).

Comment: How do you create and import your models? Do the affected models use tiling? Do you use texture atlasses?

Comment: Also please include the properties of the texture in your screen shot. I have a hunch that the texture is square and the object is not, making the image stretched in one direction.

Comment: In this context, it's important to include both an explanation and a tag of the 3D app you're using to create or prep the models. In my own experience, it's imperative to clear position, rotation and scaling prior to importing from e.g. Blender. This might be the case for other 3D apps as well.

Comment: I hadn't checked the textures were the right proportions, as I got them from our graphics guy rather than made them myself. It's all fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When imported, images default to Texture format which will make them power of two *(to be used as textures in 3D space.)* If you meant to use them as 2D textures, you will have to update the values in the [texture import setting panel](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Textures.html) to GUI. You can also change or even disable compression if higher quality is needed.